# Convex Decomposition of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

For a matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times l}$, we have the following problem of representing vectors in $\mathbf{X}$ as a convex combination of other vectors excluding the vector itself:

$\min\Vert\mathbf{X-XC}\Vert_F^2 \;\; s.t.\;\; diag(\mathbf{C})=0, \;\mathbf{c}_i\geq 0, \;\mathrm{and}\; \Vert\mathbf{c}_i\Vert_1=1$

where $\mathbf{c}_i$, is a column of $\mathbf{C}$, and $diag()$ extracts the diagonal elements of a matrix.

1) Do we have a unique solution or not?

2) What is an efficient way to solve this quadratic program?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Duplicate removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, uniqueness depends on the rank of $X$.

I would also suggest to look at the reformulate with [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) as
$$\newcommand{\vec}{\operatorname{vec}}
\|X-XC\|_F^2 = \|\vec(X) - (I\otimes X)\vec(C)\|_2^2.
$$
The constraints are fairly simple to project on (it basically constrains the columns of $C$ to be in the simplex and projecting onto the simplex can be done fast). Depending on the size and further characteristics of the problem you may use a standard QP-solver (noting that the constraints are indeed linear equality and inequality constraints) or simple projected gradient descent.

Comment: So, do we have a unique solution is $\mathbf{X}$ is full rank?

Comment: Shouldn't the LHS be $\rm \|X-XC\|_F^2$?

Comment: Oops, thanks, @RodrigodeAzevedo. Since $\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}\rank(A\otimes B) = \rank(A)\rank(B)$, full rank $X$ leads to full rank $I\otimes X$ which should give unique solutions.

Comment: @Dirk What do u mean by 'unique solutions'? Further I guess you missed the first constraint $diag(\mathbf{C})=0$, how to deal with that? Secondly for full rank case and $l>n$, $\mathbf{X}$ is not invertible, thus each signal can choose vectors from different overlapping sub-spaces i.e., multiple solutions/representations not a unique one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The constraint on the diagonal just reduces the number of variables. I did not consider if X was tall or fat...  In any case, if $I\opines X$ has no kernel, there are multiple solutions.

Comment: @Dirk What do you mean by $I \otimes X$ has no kernel? Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, previous comment was messed up.  If the kernel is trivial, solutions are unique, if not, it depends on how they relate to the constraints.